# Rhive: The messages shows: Not Connected to Hiveserver2 (But can connect HDFS)

Tags: hive

I've been trying connect R and Hive using RHive, and the needed packages(Rhive, rJava, Rserve) are all installed and the environment variables are set.  In R I am trying the following, not sure what's the reason failed to connect hiveserver, thanks :

*start R*

**>R**

*load Rhive Package*

**>library(RHive)**

*set environmental variables*

**> Sys.setenv(HIVE_HOME="/usr/local/apache-hive-0.14.0-bin")**

**> Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME="/usr/local/hadoop-2.5.1")**

*initialize the database*

**>rhive.init()**

*Check the environment variables*

**>rhive.env()**

```
   hadoop home: /usr/local/hadoop-2.5.1
    fs: file:///
    hive home: /usr/local/apache-hive-0.14.0-bin
    user name: hadoop
    user home: /home/hadoop
    temp dir: /tmp/hadoop>**
```

*Make connections*

**>rhive.connect()**

*Errors:*

```
2015-06-10 15:19:48,060 INFO  jdbc.Utils (Utils.java:parseURL(285)) - Supplied authorities: 127.0.0.1:10000
2015-06-10 15:19:48,060 INFO  jdbc.Utils (Utils.java:parseURL(372)) - Resolved authority: 127.0.0.1:10000
2015-06-10 15:19:48,061 INFO  jdbc.HiveConnection (HiveConnection.java:openTransport(189)) - Will try to open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://127.0.0.1:10000/default
2015-06-10 15:19:48,061 INFO  jdbc.HiveConnection (HiveConnection.java:openTransport(194)) - Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://127.0.0.1:10000/default
Exception in thread "Thread-39" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://127.0.0.1:10000/default: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at com.nexr.rhive.hive.HiveJdbcClient$HiveJdbcConnector.connect(HiveJdbcClient.java:337)
        at com.nexr.rhive.hive.HiveJdbcClient$HiveJdbcConnector.run(HiveJdbcClient.java:322)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://127.0.0.1:10000/default: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:215)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:163)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
        at com.nexr.rhive.hive.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:51)
        at com.nexr.rhive.hive.HiveJdbcClient$HiveJdbcConnector.connect(HiveJdbcClient.java:330)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:185)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:248)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:190)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:180)
        ... 10 more
Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected to hiveserver
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the connecting issue connecting to "hivevserver" instead of "hivesever2" and it works well; the code is as below and hope could be a reference if someone encountered the same issues:

```
    >R
    >Sys.setenv(HIVE_HOME="/usr/local/apache-hive-0.14.0-bin")
    >Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME="/usr/local/hadoop-2.5.1")
    >library(RHive)
    >rhive.init
      (
          hiveLib="/usr/local/apache-hive-0.14.0-bin",
          hadoopConf="/usr/local/hadoop-2.5.1/etc/hadoop",
          hadoopLib="/usr/local/hadoop-2.5.1/lib",verbose=FALSE
       )
    >rhive.connect("172.22.25.162",hiveServer2=FALSE,defaultFS="hdfs://master:9000")
    >tables_overview<-rhive.query("show tables") 
    >View(tables_overview)
```